# How many homomorphisms exist from $|G|=70\to |H|=91$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Given finite groups $G:|G|=70,H:|H|=91$, how many distinct homomorphisms $f:G\to H$ exist?

Noting that $|G|=7\cdot5\cdot2,|H|=7\cdot13$, and that $|f(G)| \big\vert|G|$ and $|f(G)|\big\vert|H|$, we see that $|f(G)|\in\{1,7\}$. But how do I proceed from here...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ has a subgroup of order $7 \cong C_7$. Say $x$ is the generator. $x$ and his powers are the only elements that can hope not to be in $\ker f$, because a homomorphism conserves the order of an element, and there aren't elements of order 2 or 5 or multiples of 2 and 5 in $H$.
Since $H$ has a subgroup of order $7$ too (call $y$ the generator), the homomorphisms
$x\mapsto y^i, \quad i=0,\dots, 6$ are the only possibilities.

So $7$ is the right answer.

Note that $G$ and $H$ have only one subgroup of order $7$, and that descends from Sylow's theorems.

Comment: How would the answer change if $G$ and $H$ had such orders that they had more than one (Sylow) 7-subgroup by Sylow's 3rd?

Comment: Well, in that case you may have more possibilities in $H$ for choosing $f(x)$, or more $x$ in $G$ that admit a non-zero image.

Although in that case your early reasoning would be different. Once you ruled out it's 1 or 7, it automatically implies there's only one $C_7$ in $G$